# Restore trashed app from gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

Long story short - loading an unpackaged app in Chrome resulted in my source folder being deleted from the filesystem (not happy).

App was using **Yeoman/Grunt/Bower**, so I still have all the `config` and am working through de-uglifying the minified JS from `/dist`.

Is it possible to have Grunt rebuild index.html? I've lost all the file references there in, replaced with the build version of the scripts.

Comment: This is why you use an SCM like Git. Also we don't know if grunt can build index.html because you didn't tell us how its built, and if the files that it depends on are still there.

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvious /s. I lost everything from the /app folder, still have the /bower_components and associated top-level files (bower.json gruntfile.js, package.json etc)

Comment: If you post your gruntfile.js, perhaps it would help us understand how index.html was built (and if source files might still exist).

Comment: @QuinnComendant, thanks, I got it sorted - was able to recover enough to pull it back together.